# Where will Google Cloud Build save docker image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I know that Google Cloud Build will persist `/workspace` across build steps. (As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#volumes))

But I cannot understand why these 2 build steps can persist docker image in 2 different steps (from [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers)).

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE_NAME', '.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE_NAME']
```

I think if we build new image by `docker build`, that image will be saved in a special folder, and that folder can persist across build steps.
But I cannot find any document explain that folder and location.

Is my thought right or wrong?

Please help me to clarify this.

Comment: The images are kept by the Docker service running on the platform.

Answer (score 2):

The docker images are stored in the Artifact Registary as you pushed them in this location: LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE_NAME where REPOSITORY is the Name field.[image]

Comment: After `docker push` step, that image will be saved in Artifact Registry.
But in `docker push` step, I don't know where is this image come from. It is from `docker build` step, but how this image persist across build step.

Comment: This is the public image you are using gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker   , you can check all other public images that are stored in  GCP Container Registry --> https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL